# Dynamic Dropdowns for Lists in Gravity Forms

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I want to make one of the list fields in Gravity Forms a dynamic dropdown. I have the code to make one of the fields a dropdown and the code to make a dropdown dynamic. Please can someone help me combine the two snippets of code?

Here is the code for the dynamic dropdown

```
add_filter( 'gform_pre_render_17', populate_dropdown_operations_global_tag1 );
add_filter( 'gform_admin_pre_render_17', 
populate_dropdown_operations_global_tag1 );

function populate_dropdown_operations_global_tag1( $form ) {

global $wpdb;
global $loc_id;

$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT name FROM custom_tag WHERE loc_id=$loc_id AND category='global_tag1' AND status='active' ORDER BY name ASC" );
$category = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT name FROM custom_category WHERE loc_id=$loc_id AND category='global_tag1'" );

$choices = array();
$choices[] = array( "text" => "Select ".$category->name, "value" => " " );

foreach( $results as $result ) :
    $choices[] = array( "text" => $result->name, "value" => $result->name );
endforeach;

foreach( $form["fields"] as &$field ) :
    if( $field["id"] == '36' ) :
        $field["choices"] = $choices;
    endif;
endforeach;

return $form;
}
```

And here is the code for the dropdown in a list

```
add_filter( 'gform_column_input_17_36_1', 'set_column1', 10, 5 );
function set_column1( $input_info, $field, $column, $value, $form_id ) {
 return array( 'type' => 'select', 'choices' => 'NEED TO ADD CHOICES HERE' );
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't this already work? your last foreach should add all the choices to your dropdown. What else do you need?

Comment: It doesn't work. Using the code as it is puts the choices from the first snippet as labels for the list. And then I don't know how to call the choice from the first function in to the second function. I've tried to combine them but can't get it to work

Answer (score 0):

According to you comment I show you how I would populate the dropdown with the choices from your database:

```
           add_filter("gform_pre_render_17", "example_pre_render", 10 , 3);

            function example_pre_render($form, $ajax, $field_values) {
              global $wpdb;
              global $loc_id;
              $results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT name FROM custom_tag WHERE loc_id=$loc_id AND category='global_tag1' AND status='active' ORDER BY name ASC" );
              $category = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT name FROM custom_category WHERE loc_id=$loc_id AND category='global_tag1'" );

              $choices = array();
              $choices[] = array( 
                                "text" => "Select ".$category->name, 
                                "value" => " ",
                                "isSelected" => true,
                                "price" => ""
                          );

              foreach( $results as $result ) {
                  $choices[] = array( 
                                    "text" => $result->name, 
                                    "value" => $result->name,
                                    "isSelected" => false,
                                    "price" => ""  
                                );
              }
             $form["fields"][36]->choices = $choices

             return $form;
            }
```

If this does not populate the dropdown I would debug through the code to see if $results has values and what the $form object looks like when it gets returned.

It should look something like this:

[image: Debug Example]

I know its an checkbox here, but it should work almost the same.

Comment: Thanks for your help but this doesn't work as it removes the code that changes the list field to a dropdown.

Comment: Hmmm... why do you create a list field and change it do a dropdown? You can just create a dropdown in gravity forms?

Comment: I wanted to have the row adding function.